# MongoDB - The connection is not disconnected for a long time

Tags: mongodb

I am building a system that outputs information such as visit information and page transition of the user who visited the website to MongoDB,
The MongoDB connection pool of the server of the web site became MAX and it ceased to MongoDB from the web site.

The MongoDB service is configured with the following configuration.

mongos server#1 service：mongos、config
mongos server#2 service：mongos、config、rs01arbiter
mongos server#3 service：mongos、config、rs02arbiter
node#1 service：rs01(secondary)、rs02(secondary)
node#2 service：rs01(primary)、rs02(primary)

※Originally the following state is set, but OS is restarted, primary has dropped to node # 2, but it is left as it is
  node#1 service：rs01(primary)、rs02(secondary)
  node#2 service：rs01(secondary)、rs02(primary)

From this state, we restarted the OS of node # 2.
rs 01 and rs 02 of node # 1 were promoted to primary. rs01, rs02 of node # 2 demoted to secondary.I confirmed it from the log.

However, it happened that more connections would take more than 1 to 2 hours from OS reboot on node # 2 to expire.
And the MongoDB connection pool of the server of the web site became MAX and it became not connected to MongoDB from the web site.
Normally it will be out of connection in about 30 minutes at the longest.
I thought that node # 1 works as Primary, so I thought it would work normally, but I do not know why the connection is not disconnected for a long time.

If you encounter similar events, please let me know if anyone knows the solution or workaround.

Comment: It would be helpful to specify the mongoDB version. Also check if you are using keepAlive on the connection. What is your connection pool setting?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

The version of MongoDB is "MongoDB 3.0.12".

The application connected to MongoDB is built with .net c # and is running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

TCP Keepalive remains the default setting.
Also when connecting from application socketOptions.keepAlive has not changed.

The connectionString of the application also does not set the option as follows.
<add name="config" connectionString="mongodb://user:pass@mongos1:27017,mongos2:27017,mongos3:27017/config"/>

Comment: What is the default setting for `keepAlive` on that mongoDB version? Can you try to disable it? I assume your connection pool is 5 if using the node mongoDB driver etc.

Comment: I examined KeepAlive, but it was not found in ConnectionString's Option, nor was it found on the source code of MongoDB.Driver.dll (version 1.10.0.62).
How do I know if you are using KeepAlive or not?

Comment: From the connection source application, I am connecting to MongoDB with the C # .NET driver (MongoDB.Driver.dll (version 1.10.0.62)).